# if-else inside for-each loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, foreach

I am new in programming. I have this piece of code :

```
public void findFilm ( String nameofFilm ) {  
   int index = -1;
   int i = 0;
   for( Film aFilm : list ) {  
      if( aFilm.gettitle().equals( nameofFilm )) {
         index = i;
         i++;
         break ;
      } 
   }
   if( index >= 0 ) {
      aFilm.print();
   }
   else {
      System.out.println(
         "The film " + nameofFilm + " does not belong to the collection" );
      } 
   }
```

More specifically, I want to search the list and find if it includes movies with a name same with this i insert. Any ideas ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: And what is exactly your problem? Compile errors? Runtime errors?

Comment: I think this is a question for [codereview.SE]. However I think you code is fine.

Comment: What is the question exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

`aFilm` is only local to the for-loop you need to print it within the for-loop.

```
public void findFilm ( String nameofFilm ) {  
   for( Film aFilm : list ) {  
      if( aFilm.gettitle().equals(nameofFilm) ) {
         aFilm.print();
         return;
      } 
   }
   System.out.println(
      "The film " + nameofFilm + " does not belong to the collection");
}
```

Comment: I prefer return a Film (eventually null) without printing anything.

Comment: Then `return aFilm` inside the loop and `return null` outside it.

Answer (score 1):

The `aFilm` variable is defined in the for loop. Its scope is thus limited to the loop, and the variable can't be used outside of the loop. You could rewrite the loop this way:

```
Film foundFilm = null;
for (Film aFilm : films) {
    if (aFilm.getTitle().equals(nameOfFilm)) {
        foundFilm = aFilm;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundFilm == null) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

No need for any index or incrementing counter.

And, to make the code even cleaner, you could extract the first part into its own method, and rewrite it like this:

```
Film foundFilm = findFilmByTitle(films, filmTitle);
if (foundFilm == null) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: you should all look for existing answers before answering. @Garret Hall has already answered this question with the same solution

Comment: @giorashc: Learn about race conditions in concurrent systems. Moreover, I think my answer brings some points that other answers don't.

Comment: I also find Garret's answer very different, and suboptimal. It mixes finding a film and printing it. My answer cleanly separates both parts.

Comment: Why get so defensive ? I am aware you probably wrote it while the other one posted it but I always get answers notification while writing my answers and if they look the same I cancel.

Comment: I don't want to sound defensive. But as I said, my answer is not identical to the others. If it was, and my answer was written after the previous ones, I'd delete it. With 119K reputation, don't you think I know the rules of the game?

Comment: Well did not mean to disrespect but problem is I see alot of "greedy" users just answering same "different" answers just to get some points. In your case you have enough :) so I should have thought better of it ;)

Comment: No problem. I should have put a smiley on my comment on race conditions. Re-reading it, it indeed looks defensive.

Answer (score 0):

Using a data index like a map:

```
SortedMap< String, Film > filmsByTitle = new TreeMap<>();
...
if( ! filmsByTitle.contains( newFilm.getTitle()) {
   filmsByTitle.put( newFilm.getTitle(), newFilm );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for a functional approach, e.g. via [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
public boolean containsFilm(List<Film> list, final String nameOfFilm) {
    Film film = Iterables.find(list, new Predicate<Film>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Film film) {
            return film.getTitle().equals(nameOfFilm);
        }
    }, null);
    return film != null;
}
```

Additionally, I would recommend defensively checking for `null` (film, title, etc). I;ve left the checks out to keep the example simple.

Comment: The above would throw a NoSuchElementException if the film is not there. You would need to use the overloaded `find()` method taking a default value as argument (null in this case).